# Set Category wise Discount in Magento2

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart-price-rules, discount, checkout-page

I want to set Discount Category wise.

- MEN=>5%
- WOMEN=>7%
- SHOES=>5%
- ELECTRONICS=>10% 
  If I create coupon for all rule customer can not apply multiple coupons in single order.
  How is possible? with coupon and without coupon?

Comment: You can add catalog rule for it, where you can set condition for specific category

Comment: customer can not apply multiple coupon in single order so they will get discount for single coupon at order

Comment: Catalog price rules will not have any coupon code, you simply need to add the rule and it will apply the discount to the products of that specific category

Comment: by using Catalog price rules customer dont know rule is applied it applied to catalog

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by creating either catalog price rule

1) you can set either condition OR actions in above rules

2) For **catalog price rule using condition method** just go to condition tab -> click on + sign button -> click on drop-down -> select category and select your category from just right of the textbox and save this catalog price rule

NOTE: You have to create separate catalog price rule for each category due to your discount amount

Comment: customer can not apply multiple coupon in single order so they will get discount for single coupon at order

Comment: In that case, you can use catalog price rule

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by catalog price rule for specific categories. 
For adding the rule please refer this:

> https://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/how-to-create-and-manage-catalog-price-rules-in-magento-2/

Note: You asked that customer won't be informed that the rule is applied -->the discounted price will be shown on the product detail page of the products of those specific categories.

Comment: I want customer get to know in summery anyhow http://prntscr.com/lkjnsw also it applies in original price so if discounted price is 20 and catalog proce rule is 10% it will not apply.